# When i return book, it doesn't add +1 in database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

So I'm making a library information system, and I stumbled across a problem. When I want to give the book to Library member, the program checks if there is at least 1 book in the database, if there is - it subtracts within the database, so available books are -1. But, when i try to return the book, the book is taken from a member, everything works, BUT it doesn't add + 1 to available books in the database.

Code for giving books:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7PMP6IR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BibliotekaDb;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT BookAvailability  FROM Book_list WHERE BookName = @BookName", con))
        {

            cmd2.Parameters.Add("@BookName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBoxBookName.Text;

            con.Open();
            var returnVal = cmd2.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0;
            if ((int)returnVal > 0)
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO book_issue VALUES(" + TextBoxSreachMembers.Text + ",'" + TextBoxMemberName.Text + "','" + TextBoxMemberContact.Text + "','" + TextBoxMemberEmail.Text + "','" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "', '" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "', '')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                SqlCommand cmd1 = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE Book_list SET BookAvailability = BookAvailability-1 WHERE BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("book issued");
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no books available");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("no books available");
    //MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString());
}
```

Code for Returning books:

```
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE book_issue SET DateReturnBook ='" + DatePickerReturn.ToString() + "',  BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        

SqlCommand cmd1 = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE Book_list SET BookAvailability = BookAvailability+1 WHERE BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("book returned !");
this.Close();
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support Integrated Security, I've removed the irrelevant tag from you post, however, please make sure you only tag the RDBMS you are using; otherwise you can confuse the volunteers that are trying to help you. Thanks

Comment: Iwill keep that in mind next time i post something. MySQL, SQL server, SQL , so many sql.. still dont now the difference ... sorry

Comment: SQL Server is an RDBMS owned by Microsoft. MySQL, however, is an open source RDBMS, previously owned by Sun Microsystems, and now Oracle (when they purchased Sun). Although both RDBMS, they can operate quite different, each with their own syntax and functions (SQL Server, specifically uses a query language called "Transact-SQL (T-SQL)" for example).

Comment: Do not glue strings together to make SQL - use SQL parameters always.  Storing Dates as strings is also...a bold design decision

Comment: Why don't you debug the code and see if (a) the methods you expect to run are invoked properly when they should, (b) I'd rethink your overall book querying by `string` titles, (c) previous comment, parameters over string building to build queries, (d) if for some reason you're going to stick to `string` titles queries , do a better job of validating/sanitizing based on what your titles data looks like (spaces, commas, etc etc).

Comment: check if "TextBoxBookName.Text" has any leading or trailing blanks. You might need to trim those.

Comment: Ok, so I debugged the code and found out that cmd1 after cmd1.CommandText = ... has only "" value. Empty... still haven't figured out the typo...

Comment: And the cmd.CommandText ="UPDATE book_issue.... works perfectly...

Comment: Ok, so I fixed the cmd.CommandText, and again, same problem BookAvailability-1 works, BookAvailability+1 doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

The error was a typo, I was inserting values @BookName from textboxmember name

Answer (score 0):

this line of code I think is wrong

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE book_issue SET DateReturnBook ='" + DatePickerReturn.ToString() + "',  BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
```

I think It has to be to update only record of this book only

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE book_issue SET DateReturnBook ='" + DatePickerReturn.ToString() + "' where  BookName ='" + TextBoxBookName.Text + "'";
```

because first will update all records in table **book_issue** in addition you have to add another condition to update only record of borrowed member not all records of this book